# Why the following LINQ Query's in groups is behaving differently

Tags: c#, linq

In below code I have separated the outcome into three results viz **resul1, result2, result3**.

**result3** is conjunction(AND) of **result1** and **result2**

**result1** gives - true

**result2** gives - true

**result3** gives - false

```
class QuestionModel
{
  public string QuestionId { get; set; }
  public string Response { get; set; }
  public int Score { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
  static List<QuestionModel> model = new List<QuestionModel>();
  static Program()
  {
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "1", Response = "Yes", Score = 1 });
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "2", Response = "Yes", Score = 1 });
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "3", Response = "Yes", Score = 1 });
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "4", Response = "Yes", Score = 3 });
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "4", Response = "Yes", Score = 3 });
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "5", Response = "Yes", Score = 8 });
    model.Add(new QuestionModel { QuestionId = "5", Response = "Yes", Score = 8 });

  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var result1 = model.Where(x => ( x.QuestionId == "1" && x.Response == "Yes" )
                                || ( x.QuestionId == "2" && x.Response == "Yes" )
                                || ( x.QuestionId == "3" && x.Response == "Yes" )).Any();

    var result2 = model.Where(x => ( ( ( x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score == 4 )
                                    || ( x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score > 4 ) )
                                  || ( ( x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score == 4 )
                                    || ( x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score > 4 ) ) )).Any();

    var result3 = model.Where(x => ( ( ( x.QuestionId == "1" && x.Response == "Yes" )
                                    || ( x.QuestionId == "2" && x.Response == "Yes" )
                                    || ( x.QuestionId == "3" && x.Response == "Yes" ) )
                                && ( ( ( x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score == 4 )
                                    || ( x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score > 4 ) )
                                  || ( ( x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score == 4 )
                                    || ( x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score > 4 ) ) ) )).Any();
  }
}
```

Expectation: the output of result3 should also be true

Comment: This is actually an expression failing in Rule Engine query builder, when it tries to evaluate this into expression tree and compiles, it results to false.

Answer (score 2):

Lets reformat your expression a little bit and see if we can spot the problem.

```
model.Where(x =>(
                  (
                    (x.QuestionId == "1" && x.Response == "Yes") 
                    || (x.QuestionId == "2" && x.Response == "Yes") 
                    || (x.QuestionId == "3" && x.Response == "Yes")
                  )
                  &&  
                  (
                      ((x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score == 4) || (x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score > 4)) 
                      || ((x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score == 4) || (x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score > 4))
                  )
                )
```

Okay, so now that we have our different boolean groups set out, it becomes clear why you're getting false back for this.

You're checking if the QuestionID is equal to 1,2, or 3 AND that it's equal to 4 or 5.

Obviously these groups are mutually exclusive, so it can't be both.

As an aside, you can reduce the score checks to the following use the `>=` operator:

```
((x.QuestionID == "4" && x.Score >= 4) || (x.QuestionID == "5" && x.Score >= 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

`result3` is *not* the AND of `result1` and `result2`.

`result1` is the *answer* to a *query* which asks "Do any *individual elements* of `model` satisfy some condition?".

`result2` is the answer to a query which asks "Do any individual elements of `model` satisfy some *other* condition?".

`result3` is the answer to a query which asks "Do any **individual** elements of `model` **simultaneously satisfy both conditions**?". Can you see why this is different from `result1 AND result2`?

The question you're asking for `result3` is, do any elements satisfy:

```
(((x.QuestionId == "1" && x.Response == "Yes") || (x.QuestionId == "2" && x.Response == "Yes") || (x.QuestionId == "3" && x.Response == "Yes")) && (((x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score == 4) || (x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score > 4)) || ((x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score == 4) || (x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score > 4))))
```

Adding some whitespace to make it a bit more readable:

```
(
    ((x.QuestionId == "1" && x.Response == "Yes") || (x.QuestionId == "2" && x.Response == "Yes") || (x.QuestionId == "3" && x.Response == "Yes"))
    &&
    (
        ((x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score == 4) || (x.QuestionId == "4" && x.Score > 4))
        ||
        ((x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score == 4) || (x.QuestionId == "5" && x.Score > 4))
    )
)
```

There are no elements in the list that simultaneously satisfy both the condition before the `&&` and the condition after it, because there are no elements whose `QuestionId` belongs to both `{"1", "2", "3"}` and `{"4", "5"}`.

An analogy: `model` is a basket of fruit that contains apples, bananas and oranges.

- `result1` is the answer to "Does this basket contain any apples?"
- `result2` is the answer to "Does this basket contain any oranges?"
- `result3` is the answer to "Does this basket contain any single piece of fruit that is simultaneously both an apple and an orange?".